# Spring Boot 2.2.2 RELEASE - Could not locate PropertySource : Could not extract response

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-cloud

With Spring Boot 2.2.2.RELEASE

I am seeing below error

27 Jan 2020;21:45:43.870 [main] WARN  o.s.c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator - Could not locate PropertySource: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class org.springframework.cloud.config.environment.Environment] and content type [text/html;charset=UTF-8]

Using below versions
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-batch:2.2.2.RELEASE'
    implementation 'org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-integration:2.2.2.RELEASE'

```
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config:2.2.0.RELEASE'
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-security:2.1.5.RELEASE'
```

Surprisingly, i don't see this problem when i am running application in IDE, But seeing this error when running after build.

Comment: You're mixing versions of spring cloud. Why are you not letting the bom manage the versions?

Comment: I figured it out finally. It's not due to version conflict of spring jars. While my application accessing Cloud Config server, it's authentication failing and Spring Cloud client not able to parse error properly. It's misleading WARN message.

Comment: @PavanD very helpful comment was the same case here, I have one question, I had to remove spring security dependency and also security propreties on server, because I don't really know how to setup user and password from client (java springboot microservice also), any idea? thanks